# How can i display text as form of line by line in textView?

Tags: ios4

all

textViewObj.text=@"updated My interests,updated Basics,registration
                updated My partner should be..."

How can add the above information as form o line by line in textview?

Please help me.
 Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate each line using the newline character, which is

```
@"\\n"
```

in Cocoa. Notice the double backslash

```
textViewObj.text=@"updated My interests \\n updated Basics \\n registration updated My partner should be..."
```

If you have too many commas to replace, do this

```
NSString *stringSeparatedByNewLine = [stringWithCommas stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"\\n"];

textViewObj.text=stringSeparatedByNewLine;
```